# How do I properly execute database calls on other threads?

Tags: java, android, database, multithreading, sqlite

I am really confused how I should be using threads in my Android applications for database interaction. There are too many resources and I don't know which to choose from. So I'm hoping to get more specific and focused advice on my particular situation so I have a starting point.

This is my database class structure, which works great so far:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static volatile SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
    private static DatabaseHelper mInstance = null;
    private static Context mContext;

    private static final String DB_NAME = "database.db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private static final DB_CREATE_THINGY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE blahblahblah...";
    //other various fields here, omitted

    public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
            try {
                mInstance.open();
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DB_CREATE_THINGY_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { 

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db){
        super.onConfigure(db);
        db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        mDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        mDatabase.close();
    }

    public long addNewThingy(String name) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DatabaseHelper.THINGY_COLUMN_NAME, name);
        return mDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(DatabaseHelper.THINGY_TABLE, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
    }

    public Thingy getThingyById(long id) {
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(
                DatabaseHelper.THINGY_TABLE, // table
                new String[]{DatabaseHelper.THINGY_COLUMN_ID, DatabaseHelper.THINGY_COLUMN_NAME}, // column names
                DatabaseHelper.THINGY_COLUMN_ID + " = ?", // where clause
                new String[]{id + ""}, // where params
                null, // groupby
                null, // having
                null);  // orderby
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Thingy thingy = null;
        if (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            String name = getStringFromColumnName(cursor, DatabaseHelper.THINGY_COLUMN_NAME);
            thingy = new Thingy(id, name);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return thingy;
    }

}
```

So any time I want access to the database I do `mDatabaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context);` and I am good to go. I don't make any explicit calls to `open()` or `close()` or anything like that. However right now I am making all my database calls on the UI thread, I believe (either in my onCreate or onCreateView methods or separate methods which don't invoke any new threads or anything).

How would I correctly make this threaded so that I am not performing database operations on the UI thread?

I figure I have to change all my database calls to basically do this:

1. Make any necessary edits to my database class first to ensure it will work properly in the event that multiple threads are trying to perform operations at the same time. I already tried by making my class a singleton (I think it's a singleton, anyway?) and using keywords like "volatile" and "synchronized" but maybe I am missing something somewhere.
2. Perform database operation in its own thread.
3. Somehow trigger additional code back in the appropriate function/activity/fragment that will execute once the database operation has completed.
4. Make this whole process versatile enough to where I can do it anywhere.

Am I making sense? Is this the right way to be going about all this? Is there a simple example you can make that can show me how to, for example, correctly do something like `mThingy = mDatabaseHelper.getThingyById(id);` or `mDatabaseHelper.addNewThingy(someName);` from a sample activity/fragment/etc using proper threading?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with doing `mThingy = mDatabaseHelper.getThingyById(id);` or `mDatabaseHelper.addNewThingy(someName);` on main thread if it takes few millis. Neither do Android. Platform doesn't  block db operations on main thread contrary to network ops.  Nevertheless, if you need it on other threads use `AsyncTask`.

Comment: I know that in this simple example it is quick enough to do on the main thread, but for other functions I retrieve entire lists of objects using more complex criteria so that may take more time. In other areas of the application I also do file operations (involving bitmaps / rescaling / etc) so I'd still like to learn how I need to thread these properly.

Comment: I did look into AsyncTask but I didn't understand how to use it correctly in my case. I also didn't understand the arguments AsyncTask<arg1, arg2, arg3> and the weird arguments that look like `Int...` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Simple solution using Threads

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //...

    public void addNewThingyAsync(final String name, final Callback<Long> cb) {
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                cb.callback(addNewThingy(name));
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private synchronized long addNewThingy(String name){
        //implementation...
    }

    public void getThingyByIdAsync(final long id, final Callback<Thingy> cb) {
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                cb.callback(getThingyById(id));
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private synchronized Thingy getThingyById(long id) {
        //implementation...
    }

    public interface Callback<T> {
        public void callback(T t);
    }
}
```

---

### Solution using AsyncTasks

Same as above with the following changes:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //...

    public void addNewThingyAsync(final String name, final Callback<Long> cb) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Long>(){
            @Override
            protected Long doInBackground(Void... ignoredParams) {
                return addNewThingy(name);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
                cb.callback(result);
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    //...

    public void getThingyByIdAsync(final long id, final Callback<Thingy> cb) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Thingy>(){
            @Override
            protected Thingy doInBackground(Void... ignoredParams) {
                return getThingyById(id);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Thingy result) {
                cb.callback(result);
            }
        }.execute();
    }
    //...
}
```

---

### Calling (works with both approaches)

```
long mId = ...; 
mDatabaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context);
mDatabaseHelper.getThingyByIdAsync(mId, new Callback<Thingy>{
    @Override
    public void callback(Thingy thingy){
        //do whatever you want to do with thingy
    }
});
```

Comment: I am not familiar with this `Callback` class -- how would I call these async methods from the outside Activity/fragment/etc?

Comment: I think I am also confused by seeing the double `callback.callback`

Comment: I've provided a sample call and renamed the parameterss to prevent confusion.

Comment: So is there any reason you are doing it this way as opposed to using `AsyncTask`? (out of curiosity) Is your approach more generalized/versatile?

Comment: In callback you may need explicitly return to main thread before "do whatever you want" as it's run on the other thread.

Comment: Good catch @Serg! This is probably only relevant if views are touched, but notheless important.

Comment: In my case it is possible that views are touched -- would you return to the main thread inside the callback function? Do you do this by opening up yet another thread that performs operations on the UI thread?

Comment: @user6419910 I have used Threads over AsyncTasks because it makes it easier to understand what happens. (and because coding AsyncTasks directly in Stackoverflow is kind of annoying). Give me a few minutes, I'll rewrite this using AsyncTasks. These also won't have a problem with views.

Comment: @user6419910 Then follow AsyncTask route. Get familiar with this tool because it will control swithing threads for you. It's methods designed to run in current - background - current threads order.

Comment: What would happen if you didn't put `synchronized` on something like `getThingyById`? Wouldn't the function still be run in its own thread, and still be working on a database that is volatile/has a synchronized getinstance call?

Comment: @Serg If you wanted to perform view manipulation using the original Thread/Runnable approach F43nd1r wrote, would you just  a new thread using runOnUiThread or something similar inside the callback?

Comment: @F43nd1r Is `onPostExecute` in your second example performed on the UI thread, whereas the background process is done in a separate thread?

Comment: @user6419910 all the `synchronized` on `getInstance` does is ensure that you don't create two instances if two threads simultaneously call `getInstance`. All following calls to this instance are not threadsafe, unless they are `synchronized` too.

Comment: @user6419910 yes, that is why AsyncTasks are common for background work: they provide simple methods to switch a result between threads.

Comment: So `synchronized` basically means flagging it somehow to make any other calls to it stop and say "Hey, something else might be calling this first, wait your turn"?

Comment: @user6419910 Yes, runOnUiThread(). Really I did it myself sometimes, but i don't advice it because AsyncTask is the official  Android tool to do thihgs like that.

Comment: @Serg So would you say use AsyncTask if you're doing "Background processing + View updating", Threads/Runnables if you're doing something more involved, and AsyncTaskLoaders if you're just doing a bunch of heavier background work and want it to be retained on configuration changes? (trying to learn the basics here, sorry if these are dumb questions)

Comment: @user6419910 yes. This works for all methods synchronized on the same object. E.g. a call to `addNewThingy` will be blocked if `getThingyById` is currently running. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: So basically everything in my database class should be labeled `synchronized` wherever possible?

Comment: @user6419910 a method should be synchronized if you plan to use it on more than one Thread and calling it twice in parallel would result in bad things. This might or might not apply to your methods. For example, onCreate etc. probably won't need to be synchronized. You should avoid synchronization where it is not necessary, as it induces a performance overhead.

Answer (score 0):

> How would I correctly make this threaded so that I am not performing
>   database operations on the UI thread?

Simply perform any database operations off the UI thread. A common technique involves an `AsyncTask`. For example:

```
public class GetThingyTask extends AsyncTask<Long, Void, Thingy> {

    private Context context;

    public AddTask(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Thingy doInBackground(Long... ids) {

        final long id = ids[0];

        Cursor cursor = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context).query(
            DatabaseHelper.THINGY_TABLE,
            new String[]{
                DatabaseHelper.THINGY_COLUMN_ID,
                DatabaseHelper.THINGY_COLUMN_NAME
            },
            DatabaseHelper.THINGY_COLUMN_ID + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},
            null, null, null);

        String name = null;

        if (cursor.moveToFirst() && (cursor.getCount() > 0)) {
            name = getStringFromColumnName(cursor, DatabaseHelper.THINGY_COLUMN_NAME);
        }

        cursor.close();

        return new Thingy(id, name);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Thingy thingy) {
        //Broadcast the Thingy somehow. EventBus is a good choice.
    }

}
```

And to use it (inside, for example, an `Activity`):

```
new GetThingyTask(this).execute(id);
```

Comment: Note that this code is not threadsafe. The happens-before relationship of calls is not guaranteed.

Comment: What does `<Long, Void, Thingy>` mean? What does `Long... ids` mean?

Comment: @F43nd1r Not sure I follow - wouldn't this be offset by the fact `DatabaseHelper.getInstance()` is `synchronized`?

Comment: What do you mean by `The happens-before relationship of calls is not guaranteed`?

Comment: @PPartisan only calls to methods which are syncronized on the same object are threadsafe. An object itself cannot be threadsafe, only the calls to it.

Comment: @user6419910 If you add an item with this method and then query it immediately after, you might not see it. (It is not guaranteed that add `happens before` query, altough you called add before query)

Comment: @F43nd1r Fair enough, and a good point. Thank you for pointing it out!